# problems setting NSDate using setValuesForKeysWithDictionary and JSON

Tags: ios, json, json.net

so I am happily slamming data into my system using JSON and setValuesForKeysWithDictionary until I run into an object that has an NSDate property.

The JSON contains dates with the following format:

```
BackOrderDate: "2011-03-15T00:00:00"
```

This gives me an error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "BackOrderDate"; desired type = NSDate; given type = __NSCFString; value = 2011-03-15T00:00:00
```

I am using JSON.NET with MVC and the following settings with it:

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter());
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects, Formatting.None, serializerSettings);
return Content(json);
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this issue?  I do not want to lose the use of setValuesForKeysWithDictionary since it so fricking fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using Core Data (since Core Data produces the error you posted) and that your entity has a property named “BackOrderDate” of type “Date”.

The problem is that JSON doesn't have a “Date” data type.  In your .NET code you've handled this by telling the JSON serialize to convert dates to IS-formatted strings.

You need to perform the opposite conversion when you parse the JSON data in your iOS app, before you pass the data to `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`.

You can parse a string into an `NSDate` using an `NSDateFormatter`, and you can easily find lots of examples of that on the web.

How you perform the parsing before calling `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` depends on what you're using the parse the JSON.

If you're using Apple's `NSJSONSerialization`, you should probably use the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option.  Then go into the dictionary and replace the date string with an `NSDate` object before calling `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`.

If you're using some other JSON parser (like SBJSON), I don't know the best way to do the replacement.

Comment: Here is a good alternate solution as well: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/